# Map Size not updating on map.udpateSize()

Tags: openlayers, extents

I am Using OpenLayers to publish a map. But I can't figure out the way to make the map size dynamic according to screen size. As the map remains same on every screen irrespective of the screen size. I also tried `map.updatesize()`. But that is not working too.

My code is

```
layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: 'Basemap',
    baseLayer: true,
    visible: true,

    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://mlinfomaps.in/geoserver/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'MSSDS_WS:MSSDS_BASEMAP',
            'TILED': true
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',

        // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
        transition: 0,
        crossOrigin: "anonymous"
    })
});

var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    //undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  
    extent: [7970828.0670139585, 1681517.1260521673, 9127778.927138386, 2541280.8202038296]
})

function scaleControl() {
    control = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
        units: 'metric',
        bar: true,
        steps: 4,
        text: true,
        minWidth: 100
    });
    return control;
}

var sourceMeasure = new ol.source.Vector({
    crossOrigin: "anonymous",

});
var vectorMeasure = new ol.layer.Vector({

    source: sourceMeasure,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#df1c29',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#df1c29'
            })
        })
    }),
    title: 'Measure Overlay',
});

// The Map
//var overlay = new ol.Overlay
//    ({
//        element: container,
//        autoPan: true,
//        autoPanAnimation: {
//            duration: 250
//        }
//    });


var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([76.7997, 18.6298], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 7,
    extent: projection.getExtent(),
    //minZoom:7,
    maxZoom: 12
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl, scaleControl()]),
    view: view,
    //fit: view.fit(),
    //overlays: [overlay],
    layers: [layer]

});
const extent = projection.getExtent()
map.getView().fit(extent);
map.updateSize();

window.onresize = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        map.updateSize();
    }, 200);
}
```

The map on different screen looks like this:
On my screen it looks like
[image: 1]

On my colleague's screen it looks like
[image: 2]

Can you help me get through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is a consequence of using view `extent` option. When setting view extent, your essentially saying: nothing outside this extent, top or bottom, left or right, will ever be shown on map.

Why then because of this your colleague's displayed region is cut off on top and bottom? Simply because his view height is lower then yours.

To show the whole extent at his view height, zoom would have to be lowered and more map on the right and left would have to be shown, but this is not allowed because then map outside allowed extent would be shown on the left and the right.

**EDIT** (on the basis of @Mike comment):
The above description of behavior is true, but there is a way to keep the whole extent shown, regardless of the map view width or height. You have to use `showFullExtent: true` view option.

Comment: `extent` is ok but it needs to be used in conjunction with `showFullExtent: true` to show the whole extent.

Answer (score 2):

Try using OpenLayer's `map` event listener functions instead of `window.onresize()`. Each time you resize the window, map will have to re-render the map. Have a look at these two `map` functions and try to experiment, see what happens:

> - change:view (module:ol/Object.ObjectEvent)
> - postrender (module:ol/MapEvent~MapEvent) - Triggered after a map frame
>   is rendered.
> - rendercomplete (module:ol/render/Event~RenderEvent) -
>   Triggered when rendering is complete, i.e. all sources and tiles have
>   finished loading for the current viewport, and all tiles are faded in.
>   The event object will not have a context set.

to register event listener, write this: `map.on('rendercomplete', someFunction);`

to unregister the event: `map.un('rendercomplete', someFunction);`

OpenLayers Map documentation: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html